# Minecraft 1.8 Forge (javaw.exe) keeps getting stuck in Minecraft's Main Launcher Application (MinecraftLauncher.exe)

Tags: java, process, minecraft-forge

So. I was going to play minecraft then this happened.
https://youtu.be/_UZGzfuDfS4

Why is this happening? Anyone have any idea?
Answers would Be Appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen on the non-Forge (aka vanilla) Minecraft Java version for you, as well? Does this bug happen for any other versions of Forge on your PC? Is your Java set to the correct version? How many mods are you trying to load? Have you tried going through each mod one by one and disabling them, then trying to load again?

Comment: No. Although, It happens with Any 1.8 Forge Version I download.

Comment: I Installed 1.8.9 Forge, and the same thing happens.

Comment: with 1.8, I used: archimedesshipsplus-mc1.8-v1.8, bacteria-mod-1.8, cars_and_drives_mod_1.8, ComputerCraft1.76, CustomNPCs_1.8.0-09jan16, doggystyle_1.8, doggy-talents-mod-1.8, movingworld-MC1.8-V1.8, mrcrayfishfurnituremodv3.61.8, OptiFine_1.8.0_HD_U_I7, too-much-tnt-mod-1.8

Comment: And with 1.8.9, I Used: archimedesshipsplus-MC1.8.9-V1.9-full, cfm-4.0.1-mc1.8.9, ComputerCraft1.79, CustomNpcs_1.8.9(29oct16), movingworld-MC1.8.9-V1.9-full, OptiFine_1.8.9_HD_U_I7

Comment: Can you try loading Forge 1.8 without any mods loaded, just the base Forge?

Comment: I did that, still didn't work. but now, 1.12.2 Forge does not work now! What a couple of days.

Comment: Okay, can you try uninstalling Minecraft and Forge, then re-install a fresh version of both and try again?